# Script provided by TradingView does not work (alert with multiple symbols)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

I found this script on tradingview.com when they announced "Our new alerts allow for dynamic messages." The script is supposed to trigger an alert when RSI is overbought or oversold. The problem is it does not work as intended. The alert is triggered by the RSI for which symbol you added. It appears to select at random the symbols in the symbol list at the bottom of the script. The RSI data along with the script is also Incorrect as it is sending the RSI of the symbol you originally added the study to, not the RSI of the symbol list.

Here's the alert text to show nn example of the error:

"NASDAQ:AMD, 1: RSI (50.5282994084) crossing up 70 level" alert() with multiple symbols: any (alert) function call Active NASDAQ:AMD, 1m" This doesn't make sense since the RSI of AMD did not cross over 70 at the time the alert was triggered and it shows the RSI was 50, but it wasn't even 50 at the time of the alert it was under 30.

I tried moving the "_r = rsi (close, 7)" under the "[_co, _cu]..." line, but it did not work. I also tried to convert the data to strings to see if that did anything, but it didn't work. I tried converting to Pine Script v5. Also tried different symbols and crypto. Does anyone know if this function of applying an indicator/study to multiple symbols at the same time actually works? Or, perhaps I'm missing something and it's not working because of something I'm doing wrong.

**Screenshot:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xT2E.png)

**Alert Log from TradingView:**
|Alert ID|Ticker|Name|Description|Time|
|--- |--- |--- |--- |--- |
|358732201|"NASDAQ:TSLA, 1m"|alert() with multiple symbols: Any alert() function call,"|=""session"":""extended"",""symbol"":""NASDAQ:TSLA""}, 1: RSI (72.6465706327) crossing up 70 level"|2021-12-23T14:49:00.000Z|
|358732201,|"NASDAQ:TSLA, 1m",|alert() with multiple symbols: Any alert() function call,|"NASDAQ:CFVI, 1: RSI (72.6465706327)  crossing down 30 level",|2021-12-23T14:49:00.000Z|
|358732201,|"NASDAQ:TSLA, 1m",|alert() with multiple symbols: Any alert() function call,|"NASDAQ:TSLA, 1: RSI (72.6465706327) crossing up 70 level",|2021-12-23T14:49:00.000Z|
|358732201|"NASDAQ:TSLA, 1m",|alert() with multiple symbols: Any alert() function call,|"BINANCE:SOLUSDT, 1: RSI (72.6465706327)  crossing down 30 level",|2021-12-23T14:49:00.000Z|
|358732201,|"NASDAQ:TSLA, 1m",|alert() with multiple symbols: Any alert() function call,|"COINBASE:BTCUSD, 1: RSI (69.6339491527)  crossing down 30 level",|2021-12-23T14:48:00.000Z|
|358732201,|"NASDAQ:TSLA, 1m",|alert() with multiple symbols: Any alert() function call,|"NYSE:PLTR, 1: RSI (69.6339491527) crossing up 70 level",|2021-12-23T14:48:00.000Z|
|358732201,|"NASDAQ:TSLA, 1m",|alert() with multiple symbols: Any alert() function call,|"COINBASE:BTCUSD, 1: RSI (46.7458265403)  crossing down 30 level",|2021-12-23T14:47:00.000Z|
|358732201,|"NASDAQ:TSLA, 1m",|alert() with multiple symbols: Any alert() function call,|"FTX:RAYUSD, 1: RSI (46.7458265403)  crossing down 30 level",|2021-12-23T14:47:00.000Z|
|358732201,|"NASDAQ:TSLA, 1m",|alert() with multiple symbols: Any alert() function call,|"BINANCE:ICPUSDT, 1: RSI (44.0606617081) crossing up 70 level",|2021-12-23T14:46:00.000Z|
|358732201,|"NASDAQ:TSLA, 1m",|alert() with multiple symbols: Any alert() function call,|"COINBASE:ETHUSD, 1: RSI (44.0606617081)  crossing down 30 level",|2021-12-23T14:46:00.000Z|
|358732201,|"NASDAQ:TSLA, 1m",|alert() with multiple symbols: Any alert() function call,|"FTX:ATLASUSD, 1: RSI (44.0606617081)  crossing down 30 level",|2021-12-23T14:46:00.000Z|

The script I'm referencing is:
https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/our-new-alerts-allow-for-dynamic-messages-22588/

```
//@version=4
study("alert() with multiple symbols")
f_triggerRsi(_ticker)=>
    _r = rsi(close, 7)
    _x = crossover(_r,70)
    _y = crossunder(_r,30)
    [_co, _cu] = security(_ticker, timeframe.period, [_x, _y])
    _msg = _ticker + ", " + timeframe.period + ": "
    if _co
        _msg := _msg + "RSI (" + tostring(_r) + ") crossing up 70 level"
        alert(_msg,  alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    else if _cu
        _msg := _msg + "RSI (" + tostring(_r) + ")  crossing down 30 level"
        alert(_msg,  alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

plot(rsi(close, 7), "RSI", color=#8E1599)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#C0C0C0)
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#C0C0C0)
fill(band1, band0, color=#9915FF, transp=90, title="Background")

f_triggerRsi(syminfo.tickerid)
f_triggerRsi("NASDAQ:MSFT")
f_triggerRsi("FX:EURUSD")
f_triggerRsi("NASDAQ:TSLA")
f_triggerRsi("NASDAQ:PYPL")
```

Comment: Are you checking the RSI values at the same timeframe as you set your alerts? Can you provide some screenshots (alert messages, alert log etc.) and give us more information, time/date when the issue happens? Also, are you sure your RSI length is 7 (default value is 14)?

Comment: vitruvius thank you for your response! Yes, I am referencing the RSI with 7 length. I added a screenshot and alert log to my original post. I'm using the 1 minute timeframe for testing the alert. I have been unable to get an accurate alert on any symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else was having the same issue and not knowledgeable enough with Pine Script (yet) to fix it themselves (such as myself), I am posting the solution. I received a reply back from TradingView support. They have been super helpful, kind and gave the updated script. They said the blog post with the error will be updated soon.

Here is the updated Pine Script for multiple symbols:

```
//@version=4

study("alert() with multiple symbols") 

f_triggerRsi(_ticker)=>
    _r = rsi(close, 14) 
    _x = crossover(_r,70)
    _y = crossunder(_r,30)
    _rt = barstate.isrealtime    

    [_rsi, _co, _cu, _rt_bar] = security(_ticker, timeframe.period, [_r, _x, _y, _rt])    
    _msg = _ticker + ", " + timeframe.period + ": "    

    if _co and _rt_bar  
        _msg := _msg + "RSI (" + tostring(_rsi) + ") crossing up 70 level"
        alert(_msg,  alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)    

    else if _cu and _rt_bar
        _msg := _msg + "RSI (" + tostring(_rsi) + ")  crossing down 30 level"
        alert(_msg,  alert.freq_once_per_bar_close) 

plot(rsi(close, 14), "RSI", color=#8E1599) 
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#C0C0C0) 
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#C0C0C0) 
fill(band1, band0, color=color.new(#9915FF,90), title="Background") 

f_triggerRsi(syminfo.tickerid) 
f_triggerRsi("NASDAQ:MSFT") 
f_triggerRsi("FX:EURUSD") 
f_triggerRsi("NASDAQ:TSLA") 
f_triggerRsi("NASDAQ:PYPL")
```